Simplest way to do a one-off request to an endpoint in rtk query
What is the simplest way to do a one time request in rtk query without subscribing to future cache updates. The methods I know seem overly complicated. I do require the meta properties such as isLoading/error/etc.
Method 1: downside is you have to manually track loading/error state.
export const App = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [trigger] = useLazyGetUserQuery();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetch() {
      try{
        const response = await trigger().unwrap();
        setUser(response.data);
      } catch(error) {
        setError(error)
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } 
    fetch();
  }, [trigger]);

  // do something with error/loading/data here...

Method 2: downside is that once skip becomes true, the data/error/etc properties also become undefined so you need to manually save them in state variables if you need it.
export const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const { isUninitialized, isLoading, data, error } = useGetUserQuery(undefined, { skip: user !== null });

  useEffect(() => {
    if(data) setUser(data.user);
  }, [data]);


I'd expect something as simple as:
const { isLoading, error, data, ... } = useGetUserQueryOnce();


Surely there's something like that?

I think using the unsubscribe method on the lazy hook's trigger function does what I'm looking for: trigger().unsubscribe();

The trigger function returned by the lazy hook returns an unsubscribe() method that will unsubscribe you from future updates.
function App() {
  const [trigger, { data, isLoading }] = useLazyGetUsers();

  useEffect(() => {
    trigger().unsubscribe();
  }, [trigger]);

